# Mysql query from 2 lookup tables

Tags: mysql

For a project that improves the workflow of an advertising company y use diferent tables for my query these are used:

```
clients: Contains ID, business, lastname, name, addresse, city and zoneID etc
lookupClients: ID, clientID, productID, date, part1, part2, sizeID, design, quant
lookupPrices: ID, productID, sizeID, price
products: ID, artname, image, category
size: ID, size, width, height
```

To get the informacion I need y made the following SQL-Query

```
SELECT products.ID AS PID, clients.zoneID AS ZID, clients.business, clients.address, size.size, lookupClients.quant, lookupClients.date, lookupClients.part1, lookupClients.part2, lookupPrices.price
FROM lookupClients, lookupPrices, clients, products, size, zone
WHERE lookupClients.clientID = clients.ID
AND lookupClients.sizeID = lookupPrices.sizeID
AND lookupClients.sizeID = size.ID
AND lookupClients.productID = products.ID
AND lookupPrices.productID = products.ID
AND clients.zoneID = zone.ID
ORDER BY clients.zoneID, lookupClients.sizeID, clients.business
```

This query works fine so far, I used it to build a view in mysql. But the problem is when y want to build sums of this view and sum the colums part1, part2 and price mysql returns completely false results. Has anyone an idea to improve this query to get the right sums?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause like so:

```
SELECT 
  p.ID AS PID, 
  c.zoneID AS ZID, 
  c.business, 
  c.address, 
  s.size, 
  lc.quant, 
  lc.date, 
  SUM(lc.part1), 
  SUM(lc.part2), 
  SUM(lp.price)
FROM lookupClients lc 
INNER JOIN lookupPrices lp ON lc.sizeID = lp.sizeID
INNER JOIN clients c ON lc.clientID = c.ID
INNER JOIN products p ON lc.productID = p.Id 
INNER JOIJ size s ON s.ID = lc.sizeId
INNER JOIN zone z ON c.zoneID = z.id
GROUP BY p.ID, c.zoneID, c.business, c.address, s.size, lc.quant, lc.date
ORDER BY c.zoneID, lc.sizeID, c.business
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I built a view with this query (I didn't use the sum values yet) and it shows correct data. But when I use the view with SELECT SUM( part1 ) , SUM( part2 ) , SUM( price )
FROM `viewOrders2`
WHERE PID =19
AND ZID =2 to build sums it shows strange beahiour. A sum of 160 + 90 + 90 + 90 + 90 results in 360 instead of 520.